# Eloquent - load accessor along with model data

Tags: eloquent

My model was eager loading a lot of things with accessors. I want to change it to specify accessors in each case. How do I include such accessors with the query, so that I get the basic model data plus the accessor data

Accessors would previously be eager loaded with:

```
protected $appends = [
  'status',
]
```

But if I get rid of eager loading, and I want to include this acccessor:

```
public function getStatusAttribute() {
        return self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
    }
```

Then I can do this according to the documentation:

```
$prod = \App\Product::find(736)->status;
```

That works but I don't get the basic model data.

I can't do:  `return $prod = \App\Product::find(736)->with('status')->first()`

It gives error: `Call to undefined relationship [status] on model`

So how do I add such accessors to be included with the model data?

---

**Edit:**
As Staudenmeir commented, i can do `\App\Product::find(736)->append('status');`

That solves it for single results. But how do I append data for many results?
Neither `append` or `appends` work:

This: `\App\Product::whereIn([34, 55])->appends('status');`
results in `"Method appends does not exist.",`

I saw that you can use "appends" on "->paginate()"

```
$products = \App\Product::whereIn([34, 55])
                    ->paginate(12)
                    ->appends('status');
```

But that appends it as a query string to the url. Very strange - I want to append it in the same way as for a single result in the json response.

Comment: "get the basic model data plus the accessor data": Do you want to return the model as a JSON response?

Comment: Yes :) (model data + data of accessor/s)

Comment: You can use `\App\Product::find(736)->append('status');`.

Comment: That works! (and I can put several accessors in an array). I appreciate your help!

Comment: How to use it for many results? I couldn't use $products->get()->append('status'); ("Method append does not exist.")

Comment: Use `$products->get()->each->append('status')`.

Comment: Very awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have not fetched the collection first, and then access the attribute of result.

```
$prod = \App\Product::find(736);

$status = $prod->status;
```

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I have rewritten the post, it is more about getting an accessor , not relations, and including the model with it.

Comment: But $prod->status is the same as \App\Product::find(736)->status;  , I only get the accessor data, not the model data with tit.